# WMS/WFS layers from QGIS 2.12 projects fail when loading the project in QGIS 2.18

Tags: qgis, wfs, qgis-server, wfs-t

I've been usign QGIS Server 2.12 and QGIS Desktop 2.12 for several months without problems.

Now I installed QGIS 2.18.3 to use some new features I consider them interesting but when I open my QGIS project the WFS layers (served by QGIS server 2.12) fail to load.

Is there any WFS-T protocol update in >2.12 versions?

Is it because my WFS urls have the VERSION=1.0.0 parameter and maybe QGIS Desktop 2.18 does not handle 1.0.0 requests?

[image]

EDIT 18.01.2017:

If I add the WFS layer in QGIS 2.18 it adds ok. The problem comes when trying to open a QGIS project saved in 2.12 with QGIS 2.18.

I added a layer to canvas and saved the project in QGIS 2.12, the layers' datasource is as follows:

```
<datasource>http://eudala2.getxo.eus/qgis/qgis_mapserv.fcgi.exe?map=D:\OSGeo4W\apps\qgis\bin\test\vialidad_borrar.qgs&amp;SERVICE=WFS&amp;VERSION=1.0.0&amp;REQUEST=GetFeature&amp;TYPENAME=getxo_turismo_pois_old_borrar&amp;SRSNAME=EPSG:4230</datasource>
```

If I do that in QGIS 2.18 with the exact same WFS layer I can see that the data in datasource is splitted into different params:

```
<datasource> restrictToRequestBBOX='1' srsname='EPSG:4230' typename='getxo_turismo_pois_old_borrar' url='http://eudala2.getxo.eus/qgis/qgis_mapserv.fcgi.exe?map=D:\\OSGeo4W\\apps\\qgis\\bin\\test\\vialidad_borrar.qgs' table="" sql=</datasource>
```

What could I do to open my QGIS 2.12 projects with hundreds of layers (without having to create the projects in QGIS 2.18 again) ?

Comment: do you get an error message?

Comment: @iant Yes, those layers are not loaded, and when I click on Apply button all the rows in that list turn red and won't load. I tried changing VERSION parameter to 1.1.0 and to 2.0.0 without success...

Comment: is there anything in the log file to explain what went wrong? - also can you paste one of the links in to the question it they are publicly available

Comment: @iant I edited the OP and added a url and extra info

Answer (score 1):

I made a quick node.js script that asks for a QGIS project path and creates a new .qgs with the correct WFS/WMS layers' datasource string. I know it's not the most elegant code but it worked for me. You can get it from here:

https://github.com/jaitor1/upgradetoqgis218